# How to navigate to specific screen page based on the type of user logged in?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having a mobile app with many screen (sreen A, screen B, screen C ...)

The requirement in my application to include two types of users. One type of user will have access to all screen and the second type user (not loggin) will only have access to Screen A , Screen B. How can I do that ?

My idea is store token after user loggin by `SharedPreferences`. And check the token is `null` or `not`. If `not null`, user can access all screen. But I don't know where to put this code ? At the `main.dart` or each screen ?

```
getToken() async {
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String token = sharedPreferences.getString("token");
  //print(token);
  return token;
}

//if token != null { ..can access all Screen } else { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your home screen in a Futurebuilder. use `getToken()` as the future for this future builder. Based on the data returned from your function, return the screen you want.

Answer (score 0):

you have two options:

1. create a `global.dart` file and save `getToken()` and also a variable for the storedvalue of token (so only check for the value of sharedPref once) in there. then you can access it as follow:

```
import './globals.dart' as globals;

globals.accessToken // for getting token value
//or
globals.getToken() // for getting token directly from sharedPref
```

2. use state managements like `provider`